# Problems Generating Bibliography In TexWorks

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texworks

I'm brand new to Latex and BibTex and am having more trouble than I should generating a bibliography. Just using the example from the [ShareLatex website](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX) won't work.

I used their text of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample2}

\begin{document}
Let's cite! The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's 
book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. 

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and made a separate file called sample2.bib wherein I put

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

Then, from TexWorks I run pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex, and just end up with a one page pdf with all the citation names in bold. But NO bibliography.

How can I get this working? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help,

Comment: What do your logs say ? Was the bbl file generated ?

Comment: It says
`The top-level auxiliary file: untitled-5.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file untitled-5.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file untitled-5.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file untitled-5.aux
(There were 3 error messages)`. So...I guess not. What am I doing wrong though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three problems with your setup:

- First, since you're loading the `biblatex` package without any special options, you must use `biber` rather than `bibtex`. If `biblatex` is loaded without the option `backend=bibtex`, nothing BibTeX-specific is written to the aux file. The error message you've posted indicates that you've tried to use BibTeX. Given your setup, BibTeX rightly complains that essential meta information (e.g., `\bibdata`) is missing. Either provide the option `backend=bibtex` and use BibTeX or (better) use `biber`.
- Next, assuming your sample bibliography file is called `sample2.bib`, the instruction should be `\addbibresource{sample2.bib}` rather than `\addbibresource{sample2}`. The filename extension is *required* for use with `biber`.
- Finally, since there's no entry with key `dirac` in the sample bib file, you should be getting a warning about an unresolved citation even if you run `biber` and fix the `\addbibresource` instruction.